# How to add delivery step in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I want to add delivery date step in checkout page.
I mean 
Shiping -----> Delivery ------> Payment

Answer (score 1):

There is a topic in the Magento DevDocs about adding a new checkout step. You can find it [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply:)....I have add the new step in checkout. see a below
https://prnt.sc/ip9boa
can you please help me for one other thing..current I use two module 
one is delivery date and second for add new step in checkout
So my problem is current delivery date showing in shipping step and i want delivery date in new step module........please help me

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ip9d7f